# Mail not sent from local server - 5.7.3 Client was not authenticated

Tags: c#, windows, smtp

I am running SMTP server on Windows 2012 R2. I enabled Integrated Windows Authentication on it.
When I am trying to send email from any computer, works fine, email is sent.
When I try sending email from the server that hosting the SMTP i receive following error:
The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. the server response was: 5.7.3 Client was not authenticated.

There is no SSL - for some reason server rejecting credentials when sent from it self. Any idea how to solve that?

C# code:

```
    public static void Send(string from, string to, string subject, string body)
    {
        try
        {
            using(var smtp = new SmtpClient())
            {
                using (var message = new MailMessage())
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(from))
                    {
                        message.From = new MailAddress(from);
                    }
                    message.To.Add(to);
                    message.Subject = subject;
                    message.Body = body;
                    smtp.Send(message);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

App.config:

```
  <system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp from="somemail@somedomain.com">
    <network 
      host="smtp.somedomain.com" 
      port="922"  
      userName="SMTPUser"
      password="1234567" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

Comment: Did you check the port setting with an administrator ? That port number looks odd to me...

Comment: Yes, it work fine from other machines